# Pagination.js no me hace responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas he utilizado la libreria `pagination.js` para pagina los resultados de un BD, pero no consigo que me haga, por ejemplo:

Si hay 20 paginas

< 1 - 2 -3 - 4 - 5 - 7 - 8 - 20 >

Lo pongo de forma escueta, pero claro tengo 8 paginas y en el smartphone no cabe y se me desestructura el responsive.

```
<div id="res" class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8 col-xl-9 ticloj">
 Contenido a paginar
</div>
```

Libreria:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.paginate.js"></script>
```

Cargar la libreria:

```
  <script>
    $('#res').paginate({
        items_per_page: 6
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Lo que deberías hacer es observar el width de la pantalla para modificar el valor de `items_per_page` dependiendo de la densidad que tenga la pantalla

Comment: pero `items_per_page` son los registros por página, no puedo saber cuantos van haber dentro de 6 meses